# Is there a way to remove the clear text input X in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form I've put together using Bootstrap 3. Some of the fields are for date input, and I'm using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker to pop up calendars. I have put `onkeydown="return false;"` on the input controls to prevent free text from being inserted.

The trouble is, users can still (and will) clear the text box with the little X that bootstrap puts in there. Is it possible to remove this functionality?

[image: Bootstrap input]

Here's the datepicker markup. It's enabled depending upon the index value of a drop down list. I'm using webforms:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class='input-group date' id='dateEnd'>
    <asp:TextBox ID="datepickerEnd" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepickerEnd" Enabled="False" placeholder="Specify to date" onkeydown="return false;" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code to display this `Datepicker`

Comment: So you're really trying to prevent the user from entering something that isn't a numeric date? Isn't there a better way to do that than disallowing all keyboard input? [This bootstrap 3 demo](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) doesn't have the 'X' FWIW; it's probably some script that runs on all inputs on your page that you'll need to add an exception to.

Comment: @bbvanee Code has been added.

Comment: This comes in IE only. right?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Yes, I only just realised. IE8 is my target browser for this solution also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try below code

```
.clear::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}

<input type="text" class="clear" />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n57t00bh/ Check this in IE

Answer (score 5):

The character is not inserted by `Bootstrap`, but by `Internet Explorer` from versions `10 and up`. To remove the cross option, style your input using the `::ms-clear` pseudo-selector.

```
::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```